# Inspect element not working in IE 7 with IE developer Toolbar

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I installed the IE developer toolbar in IE 7. But after that for inspecting element I enabled the

**view -> Explorer bar -> IE developer toolbar**

It displays a inspect element tool bar in bottom of the page. But it didn't show me any css styles or something that i want to inspect the elements.

Also I used the 
**firebug-lite-dev.js**
for the script

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/firebug-lite-dev.js"></script>
```

But it is not working for me.  Anybody can please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Instead of Devtools for IE7 I'd suggested you rather to install IE9. IE7 really is deprecated ; ).

Comment: In the IE dev tool, click on refresh icon (or hit f5) to reload the DOM elements. IE dev tool is kind of pain in the butt when you want to inspect iframes or JS generated elements.

Comment: I installed windows XP. IE 9 works for windows XP? I don't know about that. Can you please tell me the URL for download the IE9

Comment: Unfortenately IE9 won't work in XP. Anyhing but IE7 would be better, here's a link for IE8: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-8